# Emoji unicode does not render into emoji

Tags: html, unicode, emoji

I have the following context where I want to turn a pattern into an emoji, however what I see as a result is `&#1F600;`. The code `&#1F600;` does not render into an emoji.

Any idea why?

```
$('#m').keyup(function (){ value = $('#m').val().replace(/(\:\))/g, '&#1F600;'); $('#m').val(value); });
```

I have also tried with `U+1F600` and has the same result.

Comment: both `.val`-s ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing the 'x' for a hex entity value, `&#x1F600;`

For passing this emoji in a JavaScript string, as the character itself and not as an HTML entity, you need two characters -- JavaScript strings can only do 16-bit codepoints directly, so Unicode codepoints beyond `\uFFFF` have to be broken up into two 16-bit values, like this:

```
'\uD83D\uDE00'
```

These are called "[surrogate pairs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374069(v=vs.85).aspx)".

Alternatively, you can create an expression for the emoji character this way too:

```
String.fromCodePoint(0x1F600)
```

You can even use the emoji characters directly in your code, so long as you're saving your code in a compatible encoding, like UTF-8, and you can count on the code editors you'll be using to handle an appropriately extended character set.

Comment: Maybe it's browser dependent? It worked fine for me using Firefox.

Comment: I just opened this page in Chrome, and the emoji (a smiley) appears just fine in Chrome too.

Comment: I've added more to my answer above that might help.

Comment: based on what did you broken it down ? cause I need more emojis to convert  ? :)

Comment: I set a string to the smiley in the Chrome JavaScript console like this: `let a = '';`, then I got the values for `a.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)` and `a.charCodeAt(1).toString(16)`.

Comment: U mean for instance : `let a = 'U+1F614';
    console.log(a.charCodeAt(0).toString(16));
    console.log(a.charCodeAt(1).toString(16));` Cause by doing this I get:  `55` and `2B` and if I replace them in `'\uD55D\uDE2B'`I get some weird character.

Comment: Not `'U+1F614'`, but literally `''` -- paste the emoji itself into the console. It's a valid character in its own right, you don't have to represent it some other way, the console will accept it.

Comment: still did not work. like this ':('. And how about the replacement is that right the way I did ?

Comment: I'm not sure this is looking the same in your web browser as mine, but I was suggesting `''`, not an ASCII substitute like `':('`.

Comment: i just see the emoji itself .

Comment: Select the emoji text right off the screen where you see it in your web browser and copy/paste that into the Chrome JavaScript console. Don't try to manually retype it.

Comment: finally it works, that' interesting I even see it as an emoji string in my editor as well. I am wondering what's actually behind ?

Comment: is it a png or ?

Comment: With great insomnia comes great patience. 

Comment: @CodeHip the correct sequence for U+1F614 is `'\uD83D\uDE14'`, not `'\uD55D\uDE2B'`. You need to read up on how [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) works, as Java(script) strings use UTF-16 encoding.